# Unable to find CSRF token

Tags: python, python-requests, csrf

I am attempting to log in to this website (https://isf.scout7.com/Apps/Login) to then scrape some data using  Python and the requests library.

In the past I have followed the instructions in Step 1 on this website (http://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/) which has always worked well for me.

I believe to input the username and password, I should use login_form.login_model.username and login_form.login_model.password respectively. However with the website I'm trying to sign in to, I have been unable to find the CSRF token need to log in. I have gone through the html by inspecting the page using Chrome, but I can't find anything that resembles a CSRF token.

Am I completely missing it, or do I not need it to log in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I entered some values to login and password fields, then used my browser tools to examine http request that is sent when clicking on Login button. Here it is:

[image: screenshot]

You see - no CSRF token is sent here. So I guess you can just post `login=<login>&password=<password>&grant_type=password` (and maybe some other values/headers from my request) to `https://api.scout7.com//token` - and you will get OAuth token in response.